# SQLite: Select Alphanumeric entries without a decimal in successive row

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, pattern-matching

I have an SQLite DB comprising of a series of alphanumerical codes and descriptions. Both fields are TEXT. The coding format is a single alphabetical character followed by 2 digit numerical value - this is the parent category. Many parent categories have sub-items - where the code is extended by a decimal and then an alphanumerical value... so:

A01 is a parent category

A01.10 is a subitem

I would like to `SELECT` the codes where there are no sub-items... There are 80000 entries in this table, so going through it manually isn't ideal ;)

So, the inclusion criteria are where code [an][n][n] exists AND [an][n][n].% doesn't exist... Any ideas / guideance appreciated :)

The `TABLE` is called 'Terms' and the Code field is imaginatively called `Code`

TIA

Answer (score 0):

String processing isn't exactly SQLite's strong point but I think you get it done in a slightly round about way:

```
select *
from terms
where code not like '%.%'
  and code not in (
    select rtrim(rtrim(code, '1234567890'), '.')
    from terms
    where code like '%.%'
);
```

The idea is to first figure out which codes have sub-items and then exclude them.

Given this data:

```
id | code
 1 | a01
 2 | a02
 3 | a03
 4 | a03.1
 5 | a03.2
 6 | a01.1
```

Then that query gives you this:

```
id | code
2  | a02
```